# Possible to label alternate rules with a common suffix?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have the following rule where there are three alternates:

```
tableItem:
    Identifier (Dot Identifier)? (Dot Identifier)? (Dot Identifier)?        # simplePath
    | OpenParen selectStatement CloseParen                                  # subSelect
    | OpenParen VALUES OpenParen expr (Comma expr)* CloseParen CloseParen   # valuesClause
     // how to add in this part to all?
    (AS? Identifier)? tableSample?
    ;
```

Is there a way that I can add on the `AS IDENTIFIER` part to all? Currently, I see my only options being:

1. Don't use labels.
2. Copy-paste the line `(AS? IDENTIFIER)? tableSample?` to all three alternates.

Both of these seem sub-optimal. What would be the suggested way to do this?

Comment: Add an auxiliary rule that folds the three alts and adds suffix. `aux: Identifier (Dot Identifier)? (Dot Identifier)? (Dot Identifier)? # simplePath | OpenParen selectStatement CloseParen # subSelect | OpenParen VALUES OpenParen expr (Comma expr)* CloseParen CloseParen # valuesClause ; tableItem: aux (AS? Identifier)? tableSample? ;`

Comment: @kaby76 cool, yea that is what I ended up doing! `tableItem alias? tableSample?`